# Month "May" does not work with Moment.JS (Fiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

Why do I get "invalid date" when I try the month "may"? (it is Dutch, so that's why there is "mei")

I don't get "invalid date" when I try the month "june" (in Dutch: "juni")

I don't get it...
Check the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kULx3/)

**Script:** (Purely for testing purposes, to show that the month "may" does not work..)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newvartitle = "5 mei 2014";
    var goodformatdata = moment(newvartitle).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    var newvartitle2 = "5 juni 2014";
    var goodformatdata2 = moment(newvartitle2).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    $('.tester').append(goodformatdata);
    $('.tester').append(goodformatdata2);
});
```

**This problem is solved**, the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/kULx3/2/

Comment: I got `invalid date` when i try `juni`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the language that you're using is the **output** language. For example if you try this

```
alert(moment("5 5 2014").lang("nl").format("DD/MMMM/YYYY"));
```

the output will be

> 05/mei/2014

In order to *accept* inputs in Dutch you will have to implement it. For example create a method which takes a string as a parameter and changes Dutch months to numbers, so when you call

```
moment(toMoment("5 mei 2014")).lang("nl").format("DD/MMMM/YYYY")
```

the return value of `toMoment("5 mei 2014")` would be `5 5 2014`

An example of that would be

```
function toMoment(str){

    var result = null;
    var splitted = str.split(" ");
    var month = splitted[1];

    switch(month){
        case "mei": result = "5"; break;
    }

    return splitted[0] + " " + result + " " + splitted[2];
}
```

Comment: Do I need to do exactly the same for Maart (March)?

Comment: I actually want to have the script, but for all months, do I just add cases like this:?
`switch (month) {
case "januari": result = "1"; break;
case "februari": result = "2"; break;
case "maart": result = "3"; break;
case "april": result = "4"; break;
case "mei": result = "5"; break;
case "juni": result = "6"; break;
}`

Or do I need an if statement?

Comment: Exactly. Just write other cases as you commented :) I was hoping that you would automatically figure that out :) sorry

Comment: You might also want to use `month = splitted[1].toLowerCase();`.. Just in case someone uses a month with a capital letter.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/Bjt9L/ for a simpler solution for all months of the year.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Moment.js is set to English. This can be changed by passing the desired language into Moment.js's `.lang()` function:

```
moment.lang('en');
```

In English, the "i" in "juni" is being ignored completely. Moment.js only looks at the first three letters of the month name. "Juni" is being treated as "jun" ("June" in English) whereas there is no three-letter month which begins with "mei" in English.

Comment: Yes, I tried maart(March) and it is also not working.

Comment: @James Donelly Thanks, but when I set the language to NL, it still doesn't work. It seems that is doesn't set the language. Because you are right about the problem, it is language related..